# How can you test a certificate for expiration during https without getting a provisioning profile error?

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm making a HTTPS connection to a server and want to test what happens if the server's certificate has expired.

But if I set the phones date to several years in the future then the app cannot run because Xcode/the phone now thinks the development provisioning profile has expired.

Is there any workaround for this that doesn't involve changing the certificate on the server to a test certificate?